# transfer a file from one azure virtual machine to virtual machine over open SSH from a spring application

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, sftp

I'm using JSch library in java to transfer a file, first doing the below for connecting to a VM and its not getting connected.

```
 JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session = jsch.getSession(dto.getUserName(), dto.getVirtualHost());
    session.setPassword(dto.getPassword());
    session.setConfig(config);
    session.connect();
    ChannelSftp channel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
    channel.connect();
    channel.disconnect();

com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by "using the basic way of transferring files" what did you use specifically ?, because there are multiple ways to transfer data over Virtual machines.

Moreover, you can use the Azcopy module on the machine that you have the files on and send them over to the other VM.

This is the link for refererance:
[Azcopy official documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10)

Steps to follow if you want to use the Azcopy module:

1. **Install Azcopy** from the official documentation site, and run the CMD inside the download folder.
2. **Generate a Shared Access Signature (SAS) for the Source VM:** Create a SAS token for the file or folder you want to transfer from
   the source VM. This token will provide temporary access to the file
   with specific permissions. You can generate the SAS token using the
   Azure Storage Explorer or Azure PowerShell.
3. **Copy the file using AzCopy:** On the source VM, use the following command to copy the file or folder to the destination VM:

```
azcopy copy "https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myfile.txt?SAS_TOKEN" "https://destinationstorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/destinationcontainer/"
```

Comment: I need to send a file and fetch a file from one Virtual machine to Another virtual machine from Java Program. Using JSch for the same. but getting an invalid key error, as you id_rsa key as identity.